# What can I do to Makefile.PL so that when I run make test it runs the test suite with dancer environment set to 'test'?

Tags: perl, dancer

I would like to be able to just type "make test" in a dancer app toplevel source directory (the one that was generated by "dancer -a appname") and have it run the tests with the environment set to 'test'.

Or if anyone can point me to repository that I can refer to as a sort of "best practice for developing dancer app" for this that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some checking and found the following thread on the dancer-users mailing list:

http://lists.perldancer.org/pipermail/dancer-users/2011-March/001277.html

In a nutshell; In your test files include:

```
use Dancer::Test;
Dancer::set environment => 'testing';
Dancer::Config->load;
```

Don't do:

```
use Dancer;
```

I've not tested this though; but the user from the post states that it worked for them....

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the makefile to set the DANCER_ENVIRONMENT variable appropriately.

If I had my druthers, just using Dancer::Test would automatically set the environment though.

Comment: Modifying the makefile is not good enough as the content will be overwritten the next time I run "perl Makefile.PL". I can ask Makefile.PL to produce a differently named makefile and provide my own makefile that sets the environment variable but that would be a tad ugly. Looking through Dancer::Test source code it seems like it doesn't do that.